# Custom name for select's returned Dataset's DataTable's names

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable

I have come across a situation which I would like to name the resulting dataset's datatable's names.

For example this query will return a dataset with two datatables.

```
SELECT foo FROM t1; SELECT bar FROM t2;
```

You can rename the columns in a database using the AS keyword.

```
SELECT foo AS `abc` FROM t1; SELECT bar AS `def` FROM t2;
```

**How, if possible can I rename the returning table names.
Something like:**

```
SELECT * FROM t1 AS `customTableName`; SELECT * FROM t2 AS `customTableName2`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "AS". Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 customTableName; SELECT * FROM t2 `customTableName2`;
```

Comment: I tried that, the dataset I get says the table's names are .

"Table" and "Table1".

Comment: Nice Answer. Like this. Thx